# Is there any Software to generate ERD from SQL server DB Script? Except Inbuilt Object Explorer functionality in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, erd

I need a Software or  online website by which I can generate ER Diagram from my existing Database OR Script. Please help me out.

Comment: MS Visio can do this (Add-on needed). Tools recommendations are off-topic here - try [softwarerecs.se] instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you are searching for a free solution. Then you can try [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/). It will generate ER diagram for related tables.